# retrieve random content from a string indexed associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, random, associative-array

I am trying to retrieve a random array from a string indexed associative array. The code is as follows and I keep encountering errors:

```
$suite['heart']=1;
$suite['heart']=2;
$suite['heart']=3;
$suite['heart']=4;
$suite['heart']=5;

$rand = array_rand($suite);
$card1 = $suite[$rand];

print $card1;
```

My results have been static and continuously displaying number 5, I want it to display any of the random numbers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As stated below, you are using the same variable inside each called `heart`. You could use different names like this `$suite['heart1']=1; $suite['heart2']=2; $suite['heart3']=3; $suite['heart4']=4; $suite['heart5']=5;` which will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because all that `$suite['heart']` contains is `5`.

You are declaring `$suite['heart'] = 1;`
then redeclaring `$suite['heart'] = 2;` etc.

I think what you are looking for in your array is something more like

```
$suite['heart'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Also note that `$rand = array_rand($suite);` will only ever retrieve a direct child of `$suite` (always `$suite['heart']` if you don't have any others defined) - you will also have to pick a random value from the sub-array to get a random suit and number.

The following should work:

```
$suite['heart'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$suite['spade'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$suit = array_rand($suite);
$card = array_rand($suite[$suit]);
$card1 = $suite[$suit][$card];

print $card1;
```